# How to remove block conditionally in magento 2 using xml layouts

Tags: magento2, blocks, xml, magento-2.1.3, page-layouts

The requirement is to remove some default blocks when my custom module is enabled. So how could I remove this blocks using the admin setting configuration values. I am not creating a block that should be shown based on configuration. I want to remove already added block in default layouts.

Comment: I want to remove default block conditionally, not my custom block

Answer (score 1):

Found a better solution :

```
        <referenceBlock name="<YOUR_RFERENCE_BLOCK>">
            <action method="unsetChild" ifconfig="{module}/{section}/enabled">
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">BLOCK_NAME_YOU_WANT_TO_REMOVE</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="<YOUR-BLOCK-NAME>">
            <referenceBlock name="general" remove="true" ifconfig="{module}/{section}//enable" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: This is not working. It's removing the block regardless of the configuration settings.

Comment: Check now new answer